# win32 API on AppBars and Window Restore events

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm working on a toolbar application (I know it's archaic but it's the requirement) and having some trouble. I am using the win32 API `SHAppBarMessage` function among a number of other API calls to accomplish this task. However, I have encountered a weird issue.

Upon first launch of my application it appears docked on the Top or Bottom of the screen, depending on where it was before. On this first launch however, *after my code finishes running*, the toolbar is restored to the center of the screen in a big square. Again, I cannot step into the code where this happens, it is somewhere else.

Interestingly, if I set the `Handle` to be `IntPtr.Zero` for the first launch, this does not occur. It causes other bugs and is not a viable workaround, but it is more information about the problem.

Here is some code, for context.

The setting of the "correct" handle:

```
AppStartModule.Handle = new WindowInteropHelper(AppStartModule.ToolBarWindow).Handle;
```

The setting of the workaround 0 handle:

```
AppStartModule.Handle = IntPtr.Zero;
```

Thanks in advance, and if you need more information please let me know.

Edit: I have also tried overriding the `WndProc` event to prevent movement on the window. This also fails.

Edit: Code below

```
internal static bool RegisterAppBar(IntPtr hWnd, int uCallbackMessage)
    {
        APP_BAR_DATA abd = new APP_BAR_DATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = hWnd;
        abd.uCallbackMessage = uCallbackMessage;

        int retVal = SHAppBarMessage(ABM_NEW, ref abd);
        return retVal != 0;
    }

internal static void UnregisterAppBar(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        APP_BAR_DATA abd = new APP_BAR_DATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = hWnd;
        SHAppBarMessage(ABM_REMOVE, ref abd);
    }

internal static void DockAppBar(IntPtr hWnd, int edge, Size idealSize, bool bAutoHideState)
    {
        APP_BAR_DATA abd = new APP_BAR_DATA();
        abd.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(abd);
        abd.hWnd = hWnd;
        abd.uEdge = edge;
        APP_BAR_DATA appBarData = new APP_BAR_DATA();
        appBarData.cbSize = (int)Marshal.SizeOf(appBarData);
        int retVal = SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, ref appBarData);

        if (appBarData.uEdge != 0)
        {
            abd.rc.left = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            abd.rc.left = appBarData.rc.right;
        }
        abd.rc.right = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFULLSCREEN);
        if (edge == ABE_TOP)
        {
            abd.rc.bottom = idealSize.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            abd.rc.bottom = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
            abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - idealSize.Height;
        }

        // Query the system for an approved size and position. 
        if (!bAutoHideState)
        {
            SHAppBarMessage(ABM_QUERYPOS, ref abd);
        }

        // Adjust the rectangle, depending on the edge to which the 
        // appbar is anchored.
        switch (edge)
        {
            case ABE_TOP:
                abd.rc.bottom = abd.rc.top + idealSize.Height;
                break;
            case ABE_BOTTOM:
                abd.rc.top = abd.rc.bottom - idealSize.Height;
                break;
        }

        // Pass the final bounding rectangle to the system. 
        if (!bAutoHideState)
        {
            SHAppBarMessage(ABM_SETPOS, ref abd);
        }

        // Move and size the appbar so that it conforms to the 
        // bounding rectangle passed to the system. 
        if (appBarData.uEdge == 0)
        {
            MoveWindow(abd.hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top, abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, true);
        }
        else
        {
            MoveWindow(abd.hWnd, abd.rc.left, abd.rc.top, abd.rc.right - abd.rc.left + appBarData.rc.right - appBarData.rc.left, abd.rc.bottom - abd.rc.top, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `AppStartModule`?

Comment: For the sake of this question you can think of it as the entry point to the application. It contains the Window object (ToolBarWindow), and a number of other unrelated pieces of functionality. Thank you for the response I hope you can help

Comment: What does setting the `Handle` property do?

Comment: Handle is a static field (not property) used throughout my application for these docking events. It is not actually needed, as we could simply use ToolBarWindow to get the handle, but it exists for debugging purposes (setting it to IntPtr.Zero for example)

Comment: I am unable to post much code, but can post some. Would more help? Feel free to ask more details.

Comment: I think we need more information. Setting a static field to something or `IntPtr.Zero` isn't going to have any effect until you start using that field. We probably need to know what you're doing with that handle.

Comment: Certainly, I will update the question with some methods that use the Handle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137686/discussion-between-michael-gunter-and-alex-rosenfeld).

Comment: Hi, I will join you in chat shortly. Unfortunately the site is blocked by my company I will submit a brief request.